# cannot start tomcat6 in linux environment

Tags: java, linux, tomcat6

i just installed tomcat6 via yum

where i input a command:  service tomcat6 start

```
Starting tomcat6:                                          [  OK  ]
```

but i use the command service tomcat6 status, it shows failed

```
PID file exists, but process is not running                [FAILED]
```

i had tried the solution inside this thread

[I don't understand the results from #service tomcat6 status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281166/i-dont-understand-the-results-from-service-tomcat6-status)

but not still get it work, could anyone help?

---

Please do force my question as duplicated, i had already tried 
[PID file exists, but process is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795718/pid-file-exists-but-process-is-not-running)

, it not work for my case, see my comment

---

```
- service tomcat6 start
Starting tomcat6:                                         [FAILED] 
- service tomcat6 stop
Stopping tomcat6:                                         [  OK  ]
- service tomcat6 status
tomcat6 (pid ) is running...
```

Comment: Check logs of tomcat under `TOMCAT_HOME/logs/`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PID file exists, but process is not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795718/pid-file-exists-but-process-is-not-running) - this is likely because Apache is running on the same port.

Comment: my apache run at different port

Comment: i just resintall the tomcat6 but when i type service tomcat6 status
tomcat6 (pid ) is running... , there is no pid number

Comment: cat /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out -> This account is currently not available.